# How create push notification for all user in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building a website using ASP.NET Core and I want to send notifications to all users, such as Windows notifications, when new data is added to the SQL Server database.

I have tried implementing notifications using SignalR, but I am having difficulty combining it with toast notification. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sir, the site made this proposal to me to fit the terms of the question on this site .... in the conclusion i want create notification for all user

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a right place to but when you are asking a question you should be more descriptive. You can share code samples, you can break down your steps and so on. Then someone can have better idea where you are struggling.

I'll explain fundamentals requirements in order to make it work sending a notification to all available users. You can follow below steps.

First let start with the backend and implement SignalR.

```
// In your Startup.cs file:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {    
        endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");
    });
}

// SignalrHub:

public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendNotification(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", message);
    }
}
```

Now lets go to the frontend. First you need to add signalr script from any cdn. If you are using npm you can also install signalr npm library. You can get rit of the signalR prefix and directly import the methods. In case of mvc, please copy and paste following code blocks.

```
// First we need to make a connection with hub.
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notificationHub").build();
// When ReceiveNotification event received show the message to the users.
connection.on("ReceiveNotification", function (message) {
    toastr.success(message);
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

If you need to trigger a notification from a controller or a service,follow these steps.

```
public class PostService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public PostService(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task CreatePost(CreatePostRequest request)
    {
        // create post etc..
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", $"New Post Created: {request.Title}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, in your code, the first code is correct, and the second is a very clear code to connect to the hub, and I wrote it on the client page within the javascript tag, and the last code is in the add part of the news, but the message did not appear

Comment: -----------------------
index.cshtml
-----------
<script>
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notificationHub").build();
    // When ReceiveNotification event received show the message to the users.
    connection.on("ReceiveNotification", function (message) {
        toastr.success(message);
    });

    connection.start().catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
</script>
------------

Comment: controller 
      [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(addengnot addengnot)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(addengnot);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", $"New Post Created: {addengnot.title}");

            return View(addengnot);
        }

Comment: Can you log on the frontend If the ReceiveNotification event is triggered ?

Comment: When you run the application and add a new post the code runs correctly and save data into database but without any notification

Comment: Can you debug clients ? Do you see aby client connected ?